# In C#, what is the best way to calculate the latest in a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection of PersonTimeSheet objects that looks like this (simplified)

```
 public class PersonTimeSheet
{
        public int Year;
        public string Name;
        public int Jan;
        public int Feb;
        public int March;
        public int April;
        public int May;
}
```

where each month field represents the hours worked in that month.

I have a collection of these  I

```
  Enumerable<PersonTimeSheet> timeSheets = GetTimeSheets();
  var latestPerson = CalculateLatestPerson(timesheets);
```

and i want to find a elegant way of implementing **CalculateLatestPerson**() function above. ( calculate who has worked the most in the latest month (not necessarily December))

So for example lets say I had 3 items in my collection (just going up to May to simplify)

```
| Name  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |  May |  
| Joe   | 1   |  3  |  4  |  0  |  0   |  
| Bill  | 4   |  3  |  4  |  7  |  0   |  
| Scott | 1   |  3  |  4  |  2  |  0   |
```

I would want the function to return Bill given that he worked the most int the "latest" month where people worked.

I obviously need some type of loop backward from 12 ==> but since my fields are Names of month and not integers i wanted to see if there was an elegant way to write this function.

Comment: Can you modify your class? Use a `Dictionary<int,int>` or similar to store the values against an integer representation of each month (even an `int[]` would do since the number of months in a year isn't going to change very often :)). You can then use the existing properties to return the appropriate value. Would make it much easier to query

Comment: You didn't specify the 'latest month' in your example. And it should become a parameter anyway. Everybody has 0 hours in May.

Comment: @RGraham - note that there are calenders that have a variable number of months. Which even presses more to move to a dictionary of months.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Perhaps. But if he is representing the year as strongly-typed variables anyway we can safely assume his won't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take this approach:

```
public class PersonTimeSheet
{
        public int Year;
        public string Name;
        public int[] months = new int[12]; //months are a fixed entity so array should be the best option here
}
```

To check the value for a specific month, refer to values like this:

```
pts.months[indexOfMonth];
```

Comment: Not an answer as it isn't finding a Timesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var output = input.Where(x=>x.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
                  .Select(x=> new {x,
                                   LatestWeight = new[]{
                                        x.Jan, x.Feb, x.March, x.April, x.May
                                   }.Select((a,i)=>a + i * 31).Max()
                                  })
                  .OrderByDescending(a=>a.LatestWeight)
                  .Select(a=>a.x).FirstOrDefault();
//the output is a PersonTimeSheet, you can select what you want from it.
```

We can also use some `Reflection` to select the fields in the order they are declared, however I think using Reflection will be very unreliable. So just write all the fields and that's because of your own approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure PersonTimeSheet doesn't lend itself very well to the query that you are trying to write.  If you can change this structure then I would go with something that models date times better.  If you have to work with a list of PersonTimeSheets then I would first write a new type to represent the data better such as:

```
public class MonthWorked
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could write an extension method to convert from a PersonTimeSheet to the new type like this:

```
public static class PersonTimeSheetExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<MonthWorked> ToMonthWorked(this PersonTimeSheet personTimeSheet)
    {
        yield return
            new MonthWorked
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(personTimeSheet.Year, 1, 0),
                    Name = personTimeSheet.Name,
                    HoursWorked = personTimeSheet.Jan
                };

        yield return
            new MonthWorked
            {
                Date = new DateTime(personTimeSheet.Year, 2, 0),
                Name = personTimeSheet.Name,
                HoursWorked = personTimeSheet.Feb
             };

            yield return
                new MonthWorked
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(personTimeSheet.Year, 3, 0),
                    Name = personTimeSheet.Name,
                    HoursWorked = personTimeSheet.March
                };

            yield return
                new MonthWorked
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(personTimeSheet.Year, 4, 0),
                    Name = personTimeSheet.Name,
                    HoursWorked = personTimeSheet.April
                };

            yield return
                new MonthWorked
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(personTimeSheet.Year, 5, 0),
                    Name = personTimeSheet.Name,
                    HoursWorked = personTimeSheet.May
                };

            //...
        }
    }
```

Once all of this is in place the query becomes easy to write:

```
var person = personTimeSheets.SelectMany(p => p.ToMonthWorked())
                                         .Where(p => p.HoursWorked > 0)
                                         .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
                                         .ThenByDescending(p => p.HoursWorked)
                                         .First();
```

The variable person will now hold a MonthWorked instance with the person that worked the most for the latest month.  This goes to show the importance of designing your types so they lend themselves well to the queries that you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

if you could standardise the month name fields so they were either all full month names or all three letter month names then it would be pretty simple to use reflection to get the correct value and a simple query to get the most worked

```
        // Get the three letter month name of the current month
        string monthName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");

        // Get the correct field info
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fld = new PersonTimeSheet().GetType().GetField(monthName);

        // Order the list of data by the selected field then get the first one
        var mostWorked = data.OrderByDescending(t => fld.GetValue(t)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get bored and enjoy working with difficult class designs. Be under no misimpression, the suggestions from other answers are 'correct'. You *should* redesign your `PersonTimeSheet` to maintain the information of month ordering, year ordering, etc. However, you *might* be at the mercy of another programmers class design, so here's a direct solution to your stated question.

Your overall solution requires the following signature, a filtration and sort:

```
Func<IEnumerable<PersonTimeSheet>, IEnumerable<PersonTimeSheet>>
```

First, filter only to the latest year:

```
int latestYear = timesheets.Max(x => x.Year);
IEnumerable<PersonTimeSheet> latestYearSheets = timesheets.Where((x, i) => x.Year == latestYear);
```

Next, we will filter to the latest month. Your class spec treats months as distinct (non-ordered) members of a class. The compiler is unable to 'know' the temporal ordering of these months. However, we need to know it. So I'm going to create a way of communicating the order of months to any sorting functions etc. Firstly, I'll create an `enum` that states the order:

```
enum MonthOrder = { JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC };
```

Then a method that links your `PersonTimeSheet` to that order:

```
static MonthOrder getLatestMonth(PersonTimeSheet x)
{
    x.Dec != 0 ? return MonthOrder.DEC;
    x.Nov != 0 ? return MonthOrder.NOV;
    x.Oct != 0 ? return MonthOrder.OCT;
    // Hopefully you get the picture.
}
```

Finally, I need a method that will find the latest `MonthOrder` from a collection of `PersonTimeSheet`'s. So my overall signature would be something like:

```
Func<IEnumerable<PersonTimeSheet>, MonthOrder>
```

Looking at the overall type signature, I need a method that reduces to find the latest month. So we are making a rolling *comparison* for each `PersonTimeSheet` in the sequence and finally returning the *highest* member of that comparison:

```
MonthOrder latestMonth = latestYearSheets.Max(x => getLatestMonth(x));
```

Now we filter the `PersonTimeSheet`'s to that latest month:

```
IEnumerable<PersonTimeSheet> latestMonthSheets = latestYearSheets.Where((x, i) => getMonth(x) == latestMonth);
```

Finally, we have filtered and ordered sheets by the latest month. We now want to order by the highest number of hours worked for that month. However, your class design means that we can't just get the hours for the latest month (we don't have an accessor). So we need a function with the signature:

```
Func<MonthOrder, PersonTimeSheet, int>
```

An implementation

```
static int HoursOfMonth(MonthOrder month, PersonTimeSheet person)
{
    switch(month)
    {
        case MonthOrder.JAN:
            return person.Jan;
        case MonthOrder.FEB:
            return person.Feb;
        // Hopefully you get the point.
    }
}
```

We can now get the hours for the latest month and sort by it:

```
IEnumerable<PersonTimeSheet> finalResult = latestMonthSheets.OrderBy(x => HoursOfMonth(latestMonth, x));
```

This was more for my practise. But hopefully it illustrates that a good core class design will always win out v.s. coding around a problem. A slightly improved class design would yield your answer in significantly fewer lines.